# Resizing with position:absolute not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a resizable div like this:

```css
#item {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: solid black 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="item"></div>
```

it works perfectly in Brave but it's not resizing in firefox,

I've narrowed the problem down to `position:absolute` but if I remove it then the div doesn't resize in brave either.
So how do I keep the `pointer-events:none` while still being able to resize in firefox?

It would be much better if there was a pure css solution but a workaround using javascript wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Why would you have `pointer-event: none` here?

Comment: sure, it behaves differently in different browsers - but what is the actual purpose of it?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it's actually very imp, this sample code is a part of a bigger project & I've narrowed it down

Comment: @JaromandaX would you rather have me post 3000 lines of code explaining my entire project? if it's not possible to achieve what I'm trying to do then add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Here's the thing, you're only really after the use of pointer-events:none with resize:both. This is not supported at all across every browser breaking WYSIWYG. The solution is to create a wrapping element that resizes and it itself is clickable with point-events and the item box resizes to this wrapping dividers. and perfect, someone has answered below with such solution.

Comment: No - surely though it would not need 3000 lines of code to explain why you *need* no pointer events on a div that you want to resize, using pointer events

Comment: @JaromandaX to put it simply, I'd have to add a lot more functions to it's children div if I was to remove pointer events and it would probably increase my javascript a lot

Comment: @BGPHiJACK I was going to use that as a last resort but I was hoping maybe there was some clever hack in css?

Comment: Use it, I shared the answer. There's unfortunately not much more we can do that'd be as clean/elegant. Wrapping is common in the world of HTML, don't run from it. :3

Comment: position: absolute there or not is making no difference to me on FF Windows 10.

Comment: @AHaworth Well I'm on Linux ubuntu, could you try on that if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer would be to wrap the `pointer-events: none` element inside of another element that handles the user resizing:

```css
/* I'm using CSS logical properties in this demo, the
   inline-axis is the axis on which one would normally
   write, so in English horizontally, and the 'inline-start'
   and 'inline-end' are equivalent to the ends at which
   writing starts and stops, so in English: 'left' and
   'right'; this is - of course - different for Arabic
   and Chinese, as examples.
   Block-size is the axis on which separe 'block's are
   laid, and are perpendicular to the inline-axis; so
   vertical, in English. */
 
.wrapper {
  /* logical property, see above: */
  block-size: 10rem;
  border: solid black 0.5rem;
  /* logical property, see above: */
  inline-size: 10rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* I left this in, but I don't know if its necessary on
     the outer element in this use-case: */
  position: absolute;
  resize: both;
}

.item {
  /* background added for visibility, and fixed to prevent
     it from moving when the element is resized: */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, #ccc3 0 5px, transparent 5px 10px);
  /* positions the .item against the edges of its parent (or
     the ancestor by which its position is calculated): */
  inset: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate impedit, quo animi illo corrupti? Veniam, quo nobis eaque maxime fugiat!</div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle demo.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 0.5rem solid black;
  resize: both;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

#item {
  pointer-events: none;
  user-select: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="item">
    test can't select me.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Much easier solution in my opinion, firefox won't toggle the innards of the box. you may want to implement more CSS for stylizing the text and its format but that's it.